# RightBarButton lowered in landscape-orientation in iOS 11

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uibarbuttonitem, rightbarbuttonitem

I have a problem with the RightBarButton within an iOS-App. Whenever the device is rotated to landscape, that button lowers as seen in the screenshot. While in portrait-orientation everything looks fine.

Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no idea what caused the misplaced label on orientation-change, but I was able to solve it by using a custom UIButton as my UIBarButtonItem:

```
let rightButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: .system)
[...]
let rightBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: debug view hierarchy]

try to check the hierarchy view. I surpose RightBarButton's frame didn't work

Comment: Checked that, the button itself is placed perfectly fine, but the label inside that button is misplaced. Solved it by creating a custom view.